# Can I move string literal from String pool to heap in java ? Why?

Tags: java

Can I move a string literal from string pool to string heap in java ?
If not please explain.
I know i can move string object from heap to pool by calling intern() method of java.lang.String class.

Comment: The point would be? And are you sure you want to ask about "move" instead of "copy"?

Comment: Well, you could call `new String("whatever")` if you really wanted to, but you'd still have the literal in the pool.  But why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically String pool is just a cache of Strings inside Heap. You can't move String literal from the Pool to Heap.